# Inverting Mass Matrix for a Multibody Autodiff plant in Drake

Tags: drake

Below is the code I have- including the imports, the plant urdf and the manipulator equation function, it should be runnable to reproduce the error.

```
import logging
import pydot
import os
from copy import copy
from enum import Enum 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from IPython.display import HTML, display, SVG
# pydrake imports
from pydrake.all import (AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph, DiagramBuilder,
                         Linearize, LinearQuadraticRegulator, LogVectorOutput,
                         MeshcatVisualizer, ModelVisualizer, Parser, Simulator, StartMeshcat, ConstantVectorSource)



from pydrake.all import (
    AutoDiffXd,
    DiagramBuilder,
    JacobianWrtVariable,
    MathematicalProgram,
    MultibodyPlant,
    MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose,
    Parser,
    PiecewisePolynomial,
    PlanarSceneGraphVisualizer,
    SceneGraph,
    Simulator,
    SnoptSolver,
    TrajectorySource,
    eq,
)
```

```
### URDF

bike_urdf = """
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot xmlns="http://drake.mit.edu"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 name="Ballbot">

<link name="ground">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 -5" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="1000 1000 10" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <color rgba="0.93 .74 .4 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 -5" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="1000 1000 10" />
      </geometry>
      <drake:proximity_properties>
        <drake:mu_dynamic value="20" />
        <drake:mu_static value="20" />
      </drake:proximity_properties>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="ground_weld" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link="ground" />
  </joint>



  <link name="ball_x" />

  <link name="ball">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0" />
      <mass value="5" />
      <inertia ixx=".02" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.02" iyz="0" izz="0.02" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0" />
      <geometry>
      <sphere radius="0.33" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
      <color rgba="0.75 0.52 0.96 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <visual> 
      <!-- add a visual cue to see when the ball is rolling -->
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.2 .201 0.02" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <color rgba="0 0.1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="0.33" />
      </geometry>
      <drake:proximity_properties>
      <drake:mu_dynamic value="1" />
      <drake:mu_static value="1" />
      </drake:proximity_properties>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <link name="ball2">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0" />
      <mass value="5" />
      <inertia ixx=".02" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.02" iyz="0" izz="0.02" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0" />
      <geometry>
      <sphere radius="0.33" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
      <color rgba="0.75 0.52 0.96 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <visual> 
      <!-- add a visual cue to see when the ball is rolling -->
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.2 .201 0.02" />
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <color rgba="0 0.1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>


  </link>

  
  <link name = "frame" >
    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0.5 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass value="8" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0.5 0 0" rpy="-1.57 0 0" />
        <geometry>
        <box size="1 0.1 0.2" />
        </geometry>
        <material>
        <color rgba="1 0.52 0.96 1" />
        </material>
    </visual>
  </link>




  <joint name="theta_frame" type="continuous">
    <parent link="ball" />
    <child link="frame" />
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy = "0 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="0 -1 0" />   

    <!-- use -1 to be consistent with the planar joint having z up below -->
  </joint>

 
  <joint name="theta_wheel2" type="continuous">
    <parent link="frame" />
    <child link="ball2" />
    <origin xyz="1 0 0" rpy = "0 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="0 -1 0" />   
    <!-- use -1 to be consistent with the planar joint having z up below -->
  </joint>

  <joint name="x" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link="ball_x" />
    <!-- height is set to (radius - 0.001) to have sufficient penetration to have a normal force that supports the required frictional force -->
    <origin xyz="0 0 .329" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
  </joint>


  



  <joint name="theta_ball" type="continuous">
    <parent link="ball_x" />
    <child link="ball" />
    <axis xyz="0 -1 0" />   
    <!-- use -1 to be consistent with the planar joint having z up below -->
  </joint>

   <transmission type="SimpleTransmission" name="ball_torque">
    <actuator name="torque" />
    <joint name="theta_ball" />
  </transmission>

  
</robot>
"""
```

```
### CREATE PLANT

# parse urdf and create the MultibodyPlant
bike_plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0)
parser = Parser(bike_plant)
ConfigureParser(parser)
Parser(bike_plant).AddModelsFromString(bike_urdf, "urdf")
bike_plant.Finalize()

# obtain an autodiff copy of the plant
bike_plant_ad = bike_plant.ToAutoDiffXd()

# create a context (for double and autodiff) to use in the constraints below.
bp_context = bike_plant.CreateDefaultContext()
bp_context_ad = bike_plant_ad.CreateDefaultContext()
```

```
### Manipulator function

def manipulator_equations(vars):
    # split input vector in subvariables
    # configuration, velocity, acceleration, stance-foot force
    #print(vars.size, "vars", "nq", nq)
    assert vars.size == 3 * nq +nf + nu
    split_at = [nq, 2 * nq, 3 * nq, 3*nq +nf]
    q, qd, qdd, f, u = np.split(vars, split_at)
   

    # support this function being called with double OR autodiff vars
    plant = (
        bike_plant_ad if isinstance(vars[0], AutoDiffXd) else bike_plant
    )
    plant_context = (
        bp_context_ad if isinstance(vars[0], AutoDiffXd) else bp_context
    )

    # set compass gait state
    plant.SetPositions(plant_context, q)
    plant.SetVelocities(plant_context, qd)
    

    # matrices for the manipulator equations
    M = plant.CalcMassMatrixViaInverseDynamics(plant_context)
    print(M)
    M_inv = np.linalg.inv(M)
```

In the last light of the manipulator function I get thrown an error that  says

Exception while evaluating SNOPT costs and constraints: 'UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'inv' input from dtype('0') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'

I printed out the Mass matrix for the plant and it looks like this:

```
[[<AutoDiffXd 18.0 nderiv=15> <AutoDiffXd -1.2558880317981282 nderiv=15>
  <AutoDiffXd -1.2558880317981282 nderiv=15> <AutoDiffXd 0.0 nderiv=15>]
 [<AutoDiffXd -1.2558880317981282 nderiv=15> <AutoDiffXd 7.04 nderiv=15>
  <AutoDiffXd 7.0200000000000005 nderiv=15> <AutoDiffXd 0.02 nderiv=15>]
 [<AutoDiffXd -1.2558880317981282 nderiv=15>
  <AutoDiffXd 7.0200000000000005 nderiv=15>
  <AutoDiffXd 7.0200000000000005 nderiv=15> <AutoDiffXd 0.02 nderiv=15>]
 [<AutoDiffXd 0.0 nderiv=15> <AutoDiffXd 0.02 nderiv=15>
  <AutoDiffXd 0.02 nderiv=15> <AutoDiffXd 0.02 nderiv=15>]]
```

I think the AutoDiff may be affecting things here but not sure how else to get the inverse Mass Matrix.

I tried doing np.linalg.inv(M) and also M**(-1).

Comment: please separate you peace of code for better understanding .

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pydrake.math.inv()` for matrices of `dtype=object`, effectively for `T=AutoDiffXd` and `T=Expression`: 
https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.math.html#pydrake.math.inv

Example:

```py
import numpy as np

from pydrake.autodiffutils import AutoDiffXd, InitializeAutoDiff
import pydrake.math

def make_simple_invertible_matrix(n):
    assert n < 10
    M = np.zeros((n, n))
    x = M.reshape(-1)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] = i**(n - 1)
    return M

np.set_printoptions(linewidth=150)

A = make_simple_invertible_matrix(n=3)
# Example autodiff matrix where we want to know the derivatives w.r.t.
# each entry.
A_flat = A.reshape(-1)
A_flat_ad = InitializeAutoDiff(A_flat)
A_ad = A_flat_ad.reshape(A.shape)

Ainv = np.linalg.inv(A)
Ainv_ad = pydrake.math.inv(A_ad)

print(Ainv)
print(Ainv_ad)
print(Ainv_ad[0, 0].derivatives())
```

Example output:

```
[[ 0.93055556 -0.61111111  0.18055556]
 [-1.5         0.66666667 -0.16666667]
 [ 0.625      -0.16666667  0.04166667]]
[[<AutoDiffXd 0.9305555555555555 nderiv=9> <AutoDiffXd -0.611111111111111 nderiv=9> <AutoDiffXd 0.18055555555555555 nderiv=9>]
 [<AutoDiffXd -1.5 nderiv=9> <AutoDiffXd 0.6666666666666666 nderiv=9> <AutoDiffXd -0.16666666666666666 nderiv=9>]
 [<AutoDiffXd 0.625 nderiv=9> <AutoDiffXd -0.16666666666666666 nderiv=9> <AutoDiffXd 0.041666666666666664 nderiv=9>]]
[-0.86593364  1.39583333 -0.58159722  0.56867284 -0.91666667  0.38194444 -0.16801698  0.27083333 -0.11284722]
```